# How can I connect Python + Tornado with MongoDB on other gear?

Tags: python, deployment, tornado, openshift

I am trying to run Tornado on openshift with Auto-Scale Enabled Python 2.7 cartridge.
I remove wsgi.py because it is blocking Tornado . 
Then it fails to start :

```
$gear start
Starting gear...
HAProxy instance is started
Starting Python 2.7 cartridge (Apache+mod_wsgi)
Application directory "/" selected as DocumentRoot
CLIENT_ERROR: WSGI application was not found
```

Is that possible to run Python2.7 cardridge with scaling enable (So MongdoDB stay at separated gear , but can communicate without needing ssh tunnel?) But without actually scaling (no Apache + mod_wsgi , no HaProxy) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally get it working. Using my cartdriges you can bypass Openshift limitation of only able to connect database between scalable apps. To do that i have created two cartdriges. Using my cartdriges you can connect to DB gear with or without scaling.

First create new python application ,  unscaled, you can use my cartdridge here :
https://github.com/v3ss0n/openshift-pynado-xport

```
rhc app create pythonx http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/github/v3ss0n/openshift-pynado-xport
```

That will provide anaconda Python 2.7.8 + virtualenv + tornado + pymongo ready for use.

Then create  new mongodb app using my mongox-unbound cartdrige :
https://github.com/v3ss0n/openshift-mongox-unbound

```
rhc app create mongox http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/github/v3ss0n/openshift-mongox-unbound
```

That will create Mongo 2.6 with database named mongox and user admin , database passwor is randomly generated and prompted at end of setup.

To test it in your python app :

```
mongo = pymongo.Connection("mongodb://admin:password@MONGODB_APP_NAME-YOURDOMAIN.rhcloud.com:PORT/")
```

Using that , you can host Mongodb separately from python/php/java applications.

Shoot me questions if you need help at my github.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you use the tornado quickstart that is located here: https://www.openshift.com/quickstarts/tornado-web-server-and-python-33-on-openshift. This will get you up and running using tornado and python 3.3 with one command or click.

Comment: i am not looking for one-command-click version. Please read in full . Nevermind , i already build my own Cartdrige that compile custom version of python with tornado , with websocket and also mongodb in separate gear. I will relase it soon.

Comment: My apologies, I missed that last bit "But without actually scaling (no Apache + mod_wsgi , no HaProxy)". Anyhow, if you created a custom cartridge be sure to send it to us at http://origin.ly/.

Comment: No Problem , i have created the cartdriges and added to orgin.ly , it saids pull request created but dosen't show up in orgin.ly  , why is that? Anyways i will list them in my own answer.

Comment: it seems that Orgin.ly is not syncing since 22 days ago . Last added cart was 22days ago.